# Back to top button don't get displayed through js

Tags: javascript, scroll

The scroll top link doesn't get appear when I scroll down but when I remove the display property in CSS, it's visible always and works fine. you can see CSS for scroll-top link, below CSS of footer. So please help me let me know where and what am I doing wrong. I have save the index file with PHP extension

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
            $('#scroll').fadeIn(); 
        } else { 
            $('#scroll').fadeOut(); 
        } 
    }); 
    $('#scroll').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

```css
html,body {
    font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#slides .carousel-inner img{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    }
#slides .carousel-caption{
    top: 50%;
}
#slides .carousel-caption h3{
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer{
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    color: #d5d5d5;
    padding-top: 2rem;
}
footer a{
    color: #d5d5d5;
}
footer a:hover{
    color: #f6b31c;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footicon{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
hr.light-100{
    border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: .8rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
#scroll {
    position:fixed;
    right:20px;
    bottom:10px;
    color: #3498db;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    z-index: 1000;
    }
#scroll:hover {
    color: #f6b31c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Donation-Center</title>

    <link href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav><!-- Carousel -->
<section id="Carousel">
   <div id="slides" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/i1.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/i1.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/i1.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
       </div>
       <a class="carousel-control-prev" style="background-image: none" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next"style="background-image: none" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="logo" alt="logo">
                <hr class="light">
                <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt mr-2"></i>5th Floor, Deans Plaza Peshawar</p>
                <p><i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i>xxxxxxx@example.com</p>
                <p><i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i>xxxxxx@example.com</p>
                <p><i class="fas fa-phone mr-2"></i>xxxxxxx</p>
                <div id="footicon">
                    <p>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://www.gmail.com"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://www.instagram.com"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <hr class="light">
                <h5>Our Hours</h5>
                <hr class="light">
                <p>Monday: 09am - 05pm</p>
                <p>Saturday: 10am - 04pm</p>
                <p>Sunday: Closed</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <hr class="light">
                <h5>Quick Links</h5>
                <hr class="light">
                <p><a href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-home mr-2"></i>Home</a></p>
                <p><a href="gallery.php"><i class="fas fa-images mr-2"></i>Gallery</a></p>
                <p><a href="contact.php"><i class="fas fa-question-circle mr-2"></i>Contact</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <hr class="light-100">
                <h5>&copy; DonateForLife.com 2018</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<a href="#" id="scroll"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up"></i></a>  

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/scroll-top.js"></script>
<script src="js/fontawesome-all.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to load the "js/jquery.min.js" and the "js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js". Try to load only the "jquery-3.3.1.min.js" so remove the first min.js.

Comment: removed the first jquery .. still not working

Comment: Can you try changing fadeIn() with show(), or add a value in fadeIn(), like  fadeIn(1000).

Comment: Can you just check the console and paste the errors in red text here?

Comment: done everything but nothing is working

Comment: Vaibhav Bhanushali bro. how to do it

Comment: Try removing `overflow-x: hidden;height: 100%;width: 100%;` from the `body,html` style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you set `height: 100;` to both `html,body` in your CSS which prevents the scroll event from triggering on the `window` element because the height of the body fits to the content itself.

You can either **remove** `height: 100%;` from the `html,body { ... }` style, or you can bind the scroll event to the `body` element itself (instead of `window`):

Replace: `$(window).scroll(function(){...});` With: `$('body').scroll(function(){...});`

Answer (score 2):

Your code works, I think the issue is multiple jquery calls.  Works if I only include jquery once.  Just remove the following...

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: try removing everything excpet jquery, you can see it works.  (<script src="js/scroll-top.js"></script><script src="js/fontawesome-all.js"></script><script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>)

Comment: did you try removing the all the scripts expect the 1 jquery?

Comment: OK.  Break it down to smaller pieces.  Remove everything that isn't needed and test it.  Inspect the element in your debugger and see what is happening.  Hit F12 to open your browser inspector.  Test to see that you are actually linking to jQuery!

Comment: try adding this to see if anything changes - <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I actually think that it's that `overflow-x: hidden;` in the `html,body` style

Comment: your right, just tested that, can you remove that ? or at least remove it from the html

Comment: Alon Eitan, paste your comment as answer so i could mark it

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from the HTML.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You load a js file and load a "newer" one after it. Just load only one min.js.

Comment: i removed the first query.js but still the same problem

Comment: Is there any error on the Network tab in the Developer tool? Or the JS files has 404 Not found status?